# Term (word) extraction from text file without duplication of term using Java

Tags: java

I need the specification and implementation of a new data type that holds terms extracted from document(s). Such a data type will not allow duplication of terms in each instance. A minimum of:

1 creator method,

3 mutator methods,

3 observer methods are required.

Also,a separate test program is to be implemented to read a text document (provided by a user) and extract each term contained in the document. Extracted terms from a single document will be stored in an instance of the newly created data type,

i.e. for each text document, there will be an instance of the newly created data to hold terms extracted from the document.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far and the problem(s) you are having with it.

Comment: This is the code I have written but I am not sure it is alright:

Comment: Can someone in the house help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following helps :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test { 
  public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{
    Scanner sc2 = null;
    HashSet withoutDuplicatesHashSet = new HashSet();
    try {
        sc2 = new Scanner(new File("sample.txt"));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
        boolean b;
        while (b = s2.hasNext()) {
            String s = s2.next();
            withoutDuplicatesHashSet.add(s);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(withoutDuplicatesHashSet);

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("WithoutDuplicates.txt"));
    Iterator hashSetIterator = withoutDuplicatesHashSet.iterator();
    while(hashSetIterator.hasNext()){
        out.println(hashSetIterator.next());
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain the code?

Comment: According to API definition : HashSet in Java is a collection which implements Set interface and backed by an HashMap.HashSet can be used in place of ArrayList to store the object if you require no duplicate and don't care about insertion order.The sample file is split word by word and stored in HashSet.The HashSet is then printed to another text file.

Comment: I need the specification and implementation of a new data type that holds terms extracted from document(s).Such a data type will not allow duplication of terms in each instance.A minimum of 1 creator,3 mutator and 3 observer methods are required.Also,a separate test program is to be implemented to read a text document(provided by a user)and extract each term contained in the document.Extracted terms from a single document will be stored in an instance of the newly created data type,iefor each text document,there will be an instance of the newly created data to hold terms extracted from the doc

Comment: Hi Priyadharshini Pattabhiraman, Thanks alot, can you please help with the above?

Comment: Just have a loop and do the above mentioned logic for each file name accepted from the command line.

Comment: You might have a creator method to return an instance of the datatype (HashSet or a TreeSet that doesn’t allow duplicates)
Call the creator method whenever there is a file to be read from the main method
Mutator methods can be used to set the HashSet with the words read,populate a new file with the contents of the HashSet,a map instance - a key value pair that might hold the original document’s name and the text file without duplicates corresponding to it.
Observer methods to return any objects mentioned above.

Comment: Dear Priyadharshini Pattabhiraman, I appreciate your guidance. Please, can you give me a sample code following the above procedure you have outlined?

Comment: I still need responses from the house.

Comment: I am not sure if I have got this use-case right.Just a sample idea:
import java.io.File;
...
  File dir = new File(dirPath);
  for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
    Scanner sc2 = null;
//calling a create method    
HashSet withoutDuplicatesHashSet = createHashSet();
    try {
        sc2 = new Scanner(child);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

Comment: //Move this to a new mutator method to set the HashSet
    while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
        boolean b;
        while (b = s2.hasNext()) {
            String s = s2.next();
            withoutDuplicatesHashSet.add(s);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(withoutDuplicatesHashSet);

Comment: //Move the below to a new Mutator method
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("WithoutDuplicates.txt"));
    Iterator hashSetIterator = withoutDuplicatesHashSet.iterator();
    while(hashSetIterator.hasNext()){
        out.println(hashSetIterator.next());
    }

  }
//Creator
public HashSet createHashSet(){
return new HashSet();
} 
//Getter Methods to access HashSet - observer
public HashSet getWithoutDuplicatesHashSet(){
return withoutDuplicatesHashSet;
}
}

Comment: You could probably try reading : http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/CS2110/2014sp/style_guidelines.html#mutatoretc for developing the correct version

Comment: Hi Priyadharshini Pattabhiraman, I am confused. It is not clear. Can you write it as a complete code listing in a fresh answer the question section, instead of using the comment box? There will be better and clearer. Thanks

Comment: Hi Priyadharshini Pattabhiraman, I am confused. Can you write it as a complete code listing in a fresh answer the question section, instead of using the comment box? There will be better and clearer. Write it as a full program, not a pseudocode. The program will be structured to include one constructor, three mutators and three observer methods. Each method will indicate at its header the method's pre-conditions and post-conditions and modifiers if there is any.Separate the class containing the definition of these methods from the main method class.I think with this,it will be ok. Thanks alot.